# A Lie group $G$ be acting on a Riemannian manifold $M$. Is the map $G\times M\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $(g,x)\mapsto \lVert dg_x\rVert$ continuous?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, group-actions

The norm involved is the operator norm $\lVert T\rVert=\sup\{\lvert T(x)\rVert:|x|\leq 1\}$.

Since $g$ is smooth, of course $x\mapsto  \lVert dg_x\rVert$ is continuous. But I am having little trouble in proving the whole continuity.

Comment: What does it mean for $(g,x) \in G \times M$ to have $|(g,x)| \leq 1$?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins what we have in fact is $\lVert dg_x\rVert=\sup\{|dg_x(X): X\in T_xM,\, |X|\leq1\}$

Comment: My mistake. I misread your post.

Comment: I'm thinking about using Banach-Steinhaus in a clever way

Comment: What does $dg_x$ actually mean? Each $g$ is a diffeomorphism of $M$. At what $g$ are you differentiating the action at $x$?

Comment: @TedShifrin it's the derivative of $g:M\to M$ at the point x. $dg_x:T_xM\to T_{gx}M$. And I'm differentiating at every g.